# Дано трехзначное число. В нем зачеркнули последнюю справа цифру и приписали ее в начале. Найти это число - Pascal ABC

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

> Написать программу на Паскале: Дано трехзначное число. В нем зачеркнули последнюю справа цифру и приписали ее в начале. Найти это число.

Дело в том,что моя программа работает только в pascal.net, а в pascal abc она выдает ошибку "операнды имеют неприводимые типы" а 0 обязательно нужен, потому что если число 700 то нужно, чтобы оно выдавало 070, а не 07. Сохранить в общем ведущие нули. Указывает ошибка на строчку `z:='0'+a`. Но совсем не понимаю как пофиксить эту ошибку...И как сделать чтобы был контроль трехзначного числа? Потому что если, например, написать 45888 или наоборот 22 программа всё равно будет работать, а нужно что бы она выдавала ошибку и работала только когда 3 числа.

Моя программа которая работает только в pascal.net и выдаёт ошибку в обычном abc

```
Program DZ6;
var x,a,b,c:integer;
z:string;
begin
Writeln('Введите трёхзначное число a');
readln(x);
a:=x div 10;
b:=x mod 10;
c:=b*100+a;
z:='0'+a;
If (b=0) then writeln ('Перестановленное местами =',z)
else Writeln ('Перестановленное местами =',c);
end.
```

Comment: `a` имеет тип `integer`, его нужно преобразовать к строковому типу `z := '0' + IntToStr(a)`

Answer (score 1):

Все достаточно просто:

```
program Shift;
var
  num: integer;

begin
  Write('Введите трёхзначное число: ');
  ReadLn(num);

  if (num < 100) or (num > 999) then
    begin
      WriteLn('Введенное число не является трехзначным!');
      Exit;
    end;

  WriteLn('После перестановки = ', (num Mod 10), (num Div 10));
end.
```

Для отрицательных чисел:

```
program Shift;
var
  num: integer;
  sign: integer = 1;

begin
  WriteLn('Введите трёхзначное число: ');
  ReadLn(num);

  if (num < 0) then
    begin
      sign := -1;
      num := Abs(num);
     end;

  if (num < 100) or (num > 999) then
    begin
      WriteLn('Введенное число не является трехзначным!');
      Exit;
    end;

  WriteLn('После перестановки = ', (num Mod 10) * sign, (num Div 10));
end.
```

Comment: несимметричные проверки: или `(num div 100) < 1`, или `num > 999`

Comment: @Igor исправил, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь к строке приканкатинировать, прости оспади, число типа integer. Преобразуйте, хотя бы так:

```
z := '0' + IntToStr(a);
```

Второй вариант, можно использовать процедуру Str(), но потребуется переменная типа string.

Answer (score 0):

У вас код слишком сложный. Если вам без проверки на трёхзначность числа, то:

```
Program DZ6;
var a : integer;

begin
  Writeln('Введите трёхзначное число a');
  Readln(a);
  Print((a div 100 * 10) + ((a mod 100) div 10) + a mod 10 * 100);
end.
```

Это при входном значении 700 будет выводить 70. В случаи проверки на трёхзначность:

```
Program DZ6;
var a : integer;

begin
  Writeln('Введите трёхзначное число a');
  while true do
  begin
    Readln(a);
    if (a mod 4 = 0) and (a div 3 != 0) then break;
    Println('Неверно!');
  end;
  Print((a div 100 * 10) + ((a mod 100) div 10)+ a mod 10 * 100);
end.
```

Если надо 700 в 070 со всеми нулями, тогда:

```
Program DZ6;
var a : string;

begin
  Writeln('Введите трёхзначное число a');
  Readln(a);
  Print(a[3] + a[1] + a[2]);
end.
```

С проверкой на правильность вводимого значения в этом случии будет сложнее:

```
Program DZ6;
var a : string;

begin
  Writeln('Введите трёхзначное число a');
  while true do
  begin
    Readln(a);
    if (StrToInt(a) mod 4 = 0) and (StrToInt(a) div 3 != 0) then break;
    Println('Неверно!');
  end;
  Print(a[3] + a[1] + a[2]);
end.
```

Все программы протестированы и работают на **PascalABC.Net**